# android listview limite on characters?

Tags: android, listview

In my listview i have an image i every row, and some text to the right side of the image. I have two text strings above each other. Is it possible somehow to cut the sentence, in text string one, if it gets too long. Like putting on some limite on how many characters it may contain. If i for example wanted it to say: "Kanye West live this saturday in New Your City", but then because this sentence gets too long, my second text string disappears. So instead i want it to look like this: "kanye West live this...(cut)", and then to show the rest You have to tap the row. 
So it is possible to cut the sentence, by using some sort of limite on characters?
Hope You understand. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. In the TextView tag, add right margin (to adjust characters number you want) and add also this code : `android:maxLines="2"` and `android:ellipsize="end"`This cut your sentence by adding "..." when the right limit of the textView is reached.

You obtain something like this for your textView :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="30sp" />
```

Comment: Add `android:ellipsize="end" ` also in your textview xml element

Comment: You have to size your TextView to take the place you want in each row. And yes, use android size value like dp, sp, px, ... (you can find supported type here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: What is i want it to fill out two lines. Is it also by using this code: android:singleLine="true" ?

Comment: Hum I don't understand that. So to be clear : You want to put a long sentence on two lines and if it is too long you want to cut the second line? Or you have two different long sentences and you want to cut both of them?

Comment: You want to put a long sentence on two lines and if it is too long you want to cut the second line? Yes correct

Comment: Ok, so have a look to my edited answer. Normally it works like you want.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, don't forget to validate the answer ;).

Comment: I have done that now. Your edited answer was just what i wanted. Thank You for the help :)